# Biblatex doesn't work on Overleaf - Error occurs: BibTeX: Cannot find 'references.bib'!

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

In `packages.tex` I wrote:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

In `main.tex` I wrote:

```
\begin{document}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

This error occurs: `BibTeX: Cannot find 'references.bib'!`

I have no idea how to solve this. But it's strange, that overleaf thinks I'm using `BibTex`.

Comment: Did you include the packages.tex via '\include' or '\input' in your main.tex and is you references.bib in the same folder as the main.tex?

Comment: Yes the the packages.tex is included in the main.tex - Your right the references.bib isn't - that was the problem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question was caused by the wrong file path in `\addbibresource`. Supplying the correct path resolved the issue (see self-answer). As such this question is unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: I agree that the "BibTeX" in `BibTeX: Cannot find 'references.bib'!` is misleading. But this seems to be an artefact of how Overleaf displays error messages. On my machine `latexmk` reports the error as `Biber error: [559] Utils.pm:411> ERROR - Cannot find 'references.bib'!` and that's more or less what the actual log file from Biber (`.blg`) and the command line output say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. My `.bib`-file was in another folder so I had to write:
`addbibresource{foldername/references.bib}`